# Wanting to apply different featured images for each post

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails, blog

This is my first [wordpress website](http://www.averylawoffice.ca/averywordpress/) here and so far it'll looking good. The only thing I have left that I just can't figure out is the featured image for my blog page.
I have set the main blog banner to a default featured image that's hard coded into the header.php file (and my blog page does not have a featured image so it usually shows the default like i should), which looks like this.

```
<?php

                // Check to see if we're on a non-home-page and if the non-home-page has a featured image.
                if( !is_front_page() && has_post_thumbnail() ) {

                    the_post_thumbnail( '960, 403' );

                // if we're on the home page 
                } elseif ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && is_dynamic_sidebar('banner-widget') && is_front_page() ) {

                    dynamic_sidebar('banner-widget');

                // no featured image set
                } else {
                    echo '<img src="http://www.averylawoffice.ca/Avery-Banner-Default.jpg" alt="Avery Law Office | Summerland, BC">';
                }
                ?>
```

Which was working fine. Now I'm trying to set individual featured banners for each post but the minute I set one for the newest post the banner on the main blog page changes to that one. However all other later posts do what I want them to do.
Is there something in the header I should change or have to set in single.php that I might be missing? If you need to see a specific code please let me know. I wasn't sure what page/code to show so I started with the header conditional tag.
Any help or advice is appreciated as always!

Answer (score 0):

The code you have there *should* work based on the following assumptions

1. You have  [set a thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Setting_a_Post_Thumbnail) for each post
2. You have [enabled thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Enabling_Support_for_Post_Thumbnails)
3. You are calling that from within [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/the_loop)

If you haven't done any one of those things you *should* be getting your default image. But that's just with a cursory glance at your code, and I could be wrong on that.

Comment: That I know I've done all that. However not 100% sure where else to look. I'll just have to deal with it. It's not that bad.